# Benefits of using spread operator when iterating over an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I seen this the other day in a solution that someone provided me on another question and I am just wondering what the benefits were of using the spread operator when iterating over an array of objects other than the obvious amount of code

```js
(function() {
  var junkData = [{
      ID: 1,
      FirstName: "Abe",
      LastName: "Lincoln"
    },
    {
      ID: 2,
      FirstName: "George",
      LastName: "Washington"
    },
    {
      ID: 3,
      FirstName: "Donald",
      LastName: "Trump"
    },
    {
      ID: 4,
      FirstName: "Ronald",
      LastName: "Reagan"
    }
  ];

  for (let i = 0; i < junkData.length; i++) {
    console.log(junkData[i]);
  }

  console.log("");

  for (let i = 0; i < junkData.length; i++) {
    const item = { ...junkData[i]
    };
    console.log(item);
  }

})();
```

The only other benefit I see is, while looping,

That instead of using

> junkData[i].FirstName

we can do

> junkData.FirstName

Comment: Don’t bother to use spread here _unless wishing to create a shallow copy / new object_. Just assign the object to a variable if a convenient name is desired: `const item = junkData[i]` is sufficient, more idiomatic, and more efficient, in the shown case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use object spreading instead of Object.assign in order to create a shallow copy. This is to avoid mutating the source object if you want to follow an immutable approach, so you make a new copy and mutate the fields in the new copy only

Answer (score 0):

The Rest/Spread Properties for ECMAScript proposal (ES2018) added spread properties to object literals. It copies own enumerable properties from a provided object onto a new object.

Shallow-cloning (excluding prototype) or merging of objects is now possible using a shorter syntax than Object.assign().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax